# Find out url of the hangout started with HangoutButton

Tags: google-api, google-hangouts

I'm tring to integrate Hangout to my WebSite. I want make it possible so that one user creates a new hangout and others see the url so they are able to join. I followed Google API Docs and create a HangoutButtons. It does its job well - it creates a new hangout but I don't see a way to programmatically access the url of the created hangout (so that I could share it with other users).

Comment: Can you please add some code snippet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the URL of a Hangout, you need to create a [Hangout app](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/getting-started). To have the app automatically launched when the user clicks the Hangout button, add it to `initial_apps` parameter of the button. From within the app, you can use [`gapi.hangout.getHangoutUrl()`](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/api/gapi.hangout#gapi.hangout-functions) function to get the URL of the Hangout.

Comment: Is it possible to create a background application (not visible to the user) that would send (e. g. via ajax) a notification with hangout url to the application that launched it?

Comment: @Idsa If you don't mind you app being visible on the [side bar](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/publishing#active-apps-list), then yes.